# naturalSize API deprecated from AVAsset Class in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, deprecated, avasset

'naturalSize' is unavailable: APIs deprecated as of iOS 7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift

```
    let videoAsst = AVAsset()
    videoAsst.assetWithURL(videoUrl)
    let videoSize = videoAsst.naturalSize
```

Please help me to which API is used to get natural size in Swift

Answer (score 5):

I have found out the solution hope it will be helpful for all.

```
var clipVideoTrack = videoAsst.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] as! AVAssetTrack

// Video size
let videoSize = clipVideoTrack.naturalSize
```